# Add marker label to all lines in a graph in Stata?

Tags: graph, stata, legend

I'm trying to add a marker label (mlabel) to a graph based on a variable, but it only labels the first of the years in the graph and not the others. Is there a way to have it label all the years? My reproducible example below shows the results I'm currently getting, and I'd like to have all the lines in the graph labeled by using mlabel.

```
clear
set more off

*----- example -----

input ///
year    mpg    time    speed    
2010    10      4     32 
2010    12      5     23
2011    13      4     44
2011    13      6     43
2012    11      2     55
2012    11      5     54
2013    12      6     42
2013    13      7     48
end


separate mpg, by(year) veryshortlabel 
twoway connected `r(varlist)' time, sort mlabel(speed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the word speed 4 times to get the labeling. Here's an automated way to do that.

```
local mlabels: display _dup(`=wordcount("`r(varlist)'")') "speed "
twoway connected `r(varlist)' time, sort mlabel(`mlabels')
```

Comment: As an addendum, the hint to the solution is given in `help scatter##marker_label_options`. Specifically `mlabel(varlist)`, which specifies the possibility of a _varlist_ or _variable list_ (more than one is possible).

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Oddly, `help marker_label_options` has varname, not varlist.

Comment: Indeed. This is what through me off, initially. I suspected it was a _varlist_ before looking at the `help`, went for the `help`, somehow got to `help marker_label_options`, and hit `mlabel(varname)`. Solved it with a loop, posted, then saw your answer; I deleted mine. Went back to `help` but this second time through `help scatter##marker_label_options`. I then read `mlabel(varlist)` and posted the comment. I thought I had misread, but now I see those are two different `help files`. Don't know however how I reached the first one. The second one was through `help twoway_connected`.